# Windows Server 2012 не подключается к WiFi сети

Tags: сеть, wifi, windows-server-2012

Сервер 2012 не подключается к беспроводной сети. Только при Ethernet подключается. Захожу в "Управление сетями", а там ярлык беспроводной сети - прозрачный. Пишет "Отключено". Нажимаю "Включить" идет загрузка, но ничего не происходит потом.

Comment: Драйвер WiFi адаптера ставили? Вместе с утилитой управления? Возможно это она перехватила у Виндов управление адаптером. И вообще, посмотрите этот адаптер в виндовом Device Manager, вдруг он там криво встал.

Answer (score 2):

Встретился с той же проблемой, что помогло:

Причина: отстутствовал интерфейс работы с беспроводными сетями(Manage wireless networks)соответственно никаких wi-fi сетей было не невидно

Выполнил команду: Диспетчер Сервера – Компоненты – Добавить компоненты – Служба беспроводной локальной сети

Потом перезагрузил ПК, полностью удалил драйвер Wi-Fi из системы и заново его установил.И после этого Win 2012 сразу увидел сети Wi-Fi

Comment: Спасибо, решение помогло. Ключевое действие после установки службы это перестановка драйвера!